# Asp.net core how to store html codes into database and display them later in view?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have problem with read html code from database and displaying them.
It looks like this in my page:

[image]

And what I wanted it to look is:

[image]

I'm using [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) to stored it into database with the code below:

```
teamContent.PageContent = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(edited_content); // edited_content is the html code I posted to controller to store.

_context.Update(teamContent);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

And then I decode the html code I stored using:

```
ViewBag.content = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(content);
```

ViewBag.content is passed from controller to view for displaying.

So what's the correct way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ViewBag.content is only capable of storing strings, so although you've decoded the content to be html it will be treated as a string when processed in the .cshtml.

The way to proceed is to tell .cshtml how to handle the ViewBag.content, and in this case we want it to be treated as raw html.

If you're using Razer you will use Html.Raw:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.content)
```

Otherwise if not using Razer

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.content) %>
```

*Remember that if the content of what goes in to ViewBag.content is editable by the user that you're in dangerous territory and this is a security risk as the user can write malicious code to be executed on your site.*